# Failed to find .sys file when converting qt version from 5.1.1 to 5.3

Tags: c++, qt

I have a project in QT version 5.1.1.
I tried to check in this project if the OS version is windows 8.1 as I saw in this page http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QSysInfo.html

But this check (of OS win 8.1) available only from QT 5.2. So I converted my QT version to the latest (5.3.1), but now I have a new problem, very strange problem:

In my project I check if specific file (.sys) in the “C:\Windows\System32\Drivers" is exist. I see that the file is exist but the `QFile.exists()` return me false.

I try to look into the folder with:

```
QDir folder("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers");
QStringList list = folder.entryList();
```

And the function returned me only 7 files (.txt, .sys and etc.) when in the folder there is more than 50 files.

Can someone help me with that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer to this question:
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/47043/